# Изменить белый фон изображения на фон всей страницы при помощи CSS

Tags: css, html5

Фон всей страницы серый. Скачал небольшой логотип, естественно на странице он отображается как белый квадрат внутри которого расположен логотип.
Вопрос: как изменить/закрасить белый фон изображения в серый цвет страницы при помощи CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант сделать вручную не рассматриваю - тут вопросы и ответы по программированию.

Это конечно **не CSS**, это фильтр на **WebGL** который заменяет выбранный цвет цвет на прозрачный с определенным порогом.

Использование:

```
let img = removeColor(
    url, // адрес картинки
    255, // red
    255, // green
    255, // blue
    0.1  // порог
);
```

Этот вызов вернет `canvas`, с изображением, в котором выбранный цвет заменен на прозрачный.

```js
function removeColor(url, r, g, b, a) {

  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  loader.onload = function() { 
  
    let w = canvas.width = loader.width;
    let h = canvas.height = loader.height;

    let pid = gl.createProgram();

    shader(`
      attribute vec2 coords;
      
      void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      uniform sampler2D texture;

      void main(void) {
        vec2 uv = vec2(
          gl_FragCoord.x/${w}., 
          1. - gl_FragCoord.y/${h}.
        );
        vec4 tex = texture2D(texture, uv);
        vec3 c = abs(vec3(${r}., ${g}., ${b}.)/255. - tex.rgb);
        if (c.r < ${a} && c.g < ${a} && c.b < ${a})
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.);
        else
            gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.xyz, 1.);
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.createTexture());
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture"), 0);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    function shader(src, type) {
      let sid = gl.createShader(type);
      gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
      gl.compileShader(sid);
      gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
    }
  }
  
  return canvas;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  zoom: 87%;
}
```

```html
<img>
<script>
  let url = "https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/star.jpg";
  document.querySelector('img').src = url;
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.append(removeColor(url, 255, 255, 255, 0.1));
    document.body.append(removeColor(url, 0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

в фотошопе убрать белый фон логотипа и сохранить в формате png. При помощи css - никак, если у вас jpg/png c фоном.

Comment: Точнее, нужно сделать фон прозрачным, чтобы он мог накладываться на любую страницу.

Answer (score 3):

Решил задачку при помощи Inkscape за пару минут.

- Загружаем лого File >>> Open
- В inkscape выбираем Path >>> Trace Bitmap
- Убираем галки с чекбоксов Smooth и Stack scans
- Ставим галку Remove background
- Radio-группа выбираем Greys (whatever)
- Scans по минимуму 2
- Update >>> OK
- File >>> Export png
- Видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESXJ_0Fa0rs

Comment: 1. А не спам ли это? 2. Превращать векторную картинку в растровую - это бррррр...

Comment: @Qwertiy Не спам, для моих скромных задач решение оптимальное.

Answer (score 0):

дай Img класс, в css background-color: цвет твоего фона, готово

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]