# Как обмануть WebGL в плане CORS: The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, webgl, cors, pixijs

Я подменял png картинку на свою при помощи Requestly и поставил на сервере с картинкой заголовки, разрешающие корс:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Заголовки работают, я проверял. Но Пикси, использующий WebGl, всё равно недоволен:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.
    at n.upload (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:8:23686)
    at t.updateTexture (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:13:7068)
    at e.bindTexture (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:13:14706)
    at e.flush (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:15:1438)
    at e.stop (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:15:1847)
    at e.setObjectRenderer (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:13:12588)
    at e._renderWebGL (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:11:13151)
    at e.renderWebGL (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:10:23281)
    at e.renderWebGL (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:10:23357)
    at e.renderWebGL (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js:10:23357)
```

Можно как-то его обмануть, не прибегая к подмене ещё и пикси? Возможно, надо как-то модифицировать заголовки с сервера? Выполнить до загрузки страницы js код, где будет согласие клиента на корс? Иначе самый грустный вариант - WebGL нужно не только разрешение сервера, но и пикси, и придётся изменять (и подменять) уже код пикси. Если так, то кому из этих нечитаемых абвгд ставить crossOrigin = "anonymous";?

Answer (score 3):

нужно к загружаемому изображению добавлять `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";`

```
let loader = new Image();
loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
loader.src = url;  
loader.onload = function() { 

    ... use image webgl code ...

}
```

Вот [в этом сообщении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950594/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-css/950600#950600) можно посмотреть рабочий пример

Вариант номер 2 - обойти cors каким либо способом (свой прокси или [вот](https://corsproxy.github.io/))

Comment: Это грустный вариант с подменой кода пикси. Я не вижу в его коде никаких new Image(), так что встаёт вопрос: кому ставить .crossOrigin = "anonymous": e, t, n или кому-то там ещё?

Comment: @JediKnight https://corsproxy.github.io/

Comment: Использование прокси вызывает ту же ошибку. Я писал, что сервер с картинкой мой и я настроил там разрешение корс. Но ещё необходимо разрешение со стороны клиента (пикси). В этом и проблема

Comment: @JediKnight так если у вас свой сервер, зачем корс? загружайте без него

Comment: Я подменяю картинку для браузерки. Мой сервер - с моей картинкой. Если отключить на нём корс, он не будет давать разрешения на использование этой картинки, она не будет работать, та же ошибка (я проверил). Если включить (я написал в вопросе, как я это сделал), то всё равно не будет разрешения со стороны клиента (пикси), вебгл не примет картинку.

Comment: покажите как вы загружаете картинку и саму страницу с webgl

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90555/discussion-between-jedi-knight-and-stranger-in-the-q).